# Adding text at the end of an annotated line in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I need to add text to the free body diagrams that I need to model for my task but the way my professors expect me to do it is not working so I was wondering how I can do it

This is the code I have written for my task

```
%work assignment 2
annotation("rectangle",[.1 .2 .5 .4]);
annotation("line",[.6 .8],[.4 .4]);
annotation("textarrow",[.6 .8],[.4 .55]);
'string'; 
('F=mg');
annotation("textarrow",[.35 .35],[.45 .8]);
annotation("textarrow",[.35 .35],[.4 .1]);
```

now I need to add labels to the end of the arrows and according to the task pdf I was supposed to use string to add the text but that did seem to do anything so I was wondering how I could. I am also not very good at matlab so I would appreciate if you guys could tell me where to change the code.

This is the output, the f=mg in the string bit is supposed to go on the slanted line and the other 2 arrows will also need text:

[image: output figure]

Comment: Look at the examples [in the docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html), you can add text to the start of the arrow using the "string" property. You can also add text to your figure using `text`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid MATLAB syntax, whilst it won't produce an error the 2nd and 3rd lines are basically doing nothing:

```
annotation("textarrow",[.6 .8],[.4 .55]);
'string'; 
('F=mg');
```

The `String` name-value pair should be within the brackets of the call to `annotation`, because they are inputs to that function.

```
annotation("textarrow",[.6 .8],[.4 .55], 'string', 'F=mg');
```

If you want to split it over multiple lines you need `...` for line continuation

```
annotation("textarrow",[.6 .8],[.4 .55], ...
    'string', 'F=mg');
```

Reference for the documentation: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.shape.textarrow-properties.html

[image: plot]

If you want text somewhere other than the start of the arrow, you could just add a 2nd `annotation` which is a `textbox` with the same coordinate system as the arrows, or a `text` object with coordinates matching your axes.